# how to ignore where condition results and select remained results in sql server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle, postgresql

I have a table with 17 records. I select rows by a where condition such as below query:

```
SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE (c1='AA' and c3=13)
```

2 records were the results of this query.
now i want to select the 15 records of table T1!!!
i add the `not` operator before the where condition like:

```
SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE not (c1='AA' and c3=13)
```

14 records were the results of this query. but the Table has 17 records
it's not possible to use `EXCEPT` clause, because this clause only selects distinct records.

Comment: can you post the sample data?

Comment: yes. how can i post the data?

Comment: paste the data in the question as text

Comment: Most probably there is `null` value in `c1` or `c3` column. Try `isnull` or `nullif` functions.

Comment: What about `SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE c1<>'AA' and c3<>13)`

Answer (score 2):

What if i use `EXISTS` ?? for SQL Server

```
select * from t1 t
where not exists(
         select * from t1 where (t.c1='AA' and t.c3=13)
)
```

Comment: Your subquery isn't correlated.

Comment: no. this is not correct, i test your query, and the results was 0 records. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_exists.asp    the exists returns true or false. if only on rows exists in subquery, select all rows. if not exists, returns 0 records,  @Yogesh Sharma

Comment: @RogerWolf,   Do you know the solution

Answer (score 0):

In case Id is Duplicate then Use Row_number() function.

```
SELECT T1.* FROM T1 
          LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE (c1='AA' AND c3=13)) AS T2 
            ON(T1.ID=T2.ID) WHERE T2.ID IS NULL;
```

Comment: thanks for your solution, but RowNumber() requir a order by, and it is additional cost

Comment: Yes but ,we don't have unique columns so use "Row_number()over(order   by (select 1)) " inside derived tables and join them.

Comment: can you send a sample with Row_number(), i am new with that.

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT * FROM t1
               WHERE PrimaryKey_Col not in (
                 SELECT PrimaryKey_Col FROM t1 WHERE t.c1='AA' and t.c3=13
                                           );
```

Note : This query easily work Based on PrimaryKey

Comment: i want a general query and a table maybe had not primary key

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this, EXCEPT Clause

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM 
(
    SELECT * FROM T1
    EXCEPT
    SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE (c1='AA' and c3=13)
)k
```

Comment: return only distinct rows

Comment: Updated the solution.

Comment: EXCEPT returns distinct rows, but i want all rows, not only distincts